# How to hide files/file implementation in a private podspec?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I created a private cocoapod framework and distributed it.Now i am able to download it via pods. But upon pod install all files and it's implementation is present. I want to hide the files or its implementation. Is there any way to do ? When i add s.exclude_files to hide certain files, its shows error with pod spec lint command stating s.source_files not able to access the files added in s.exclude_files.

I only want certain files to be accessible and other file's implementation should be hidden.

Comment: Use a `.framework`, compile lib `.a` instead ?

Comment: hi @Larme thanks for the reply...when i use .framework file its throwing error with one of my dependency CryptoSwift...is there any annotation or podspec attribute for the same ?